# Auto generate serial number, no repeat, no change on page refresh until form saved

Tags: javascript

I have a form on a page in which I have a reference number input field.

I would like to generate a reference number like `C0001`. Currently I am entering it manually, but I would like to generate automatically and currently it's on `C0017`. I don't want to increase the number on page refresh, and I also don't want it to repeat once it's saved. I also would like to call the script function into the input field.

```js
var seq = 0;

function myFunction() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("seq")) {
    seq = +localStorage.getItem("seq") + 1;
    localStorage.setItem("seq", seq);
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("seq", 2218);
    seq = 2218;
  }
  document.getElementById("reference_no").value = seq;
}
```

```html
<input id="reference_no" autocomplete="off" name="reference_no" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('reference_no'); ?>" />
```

Comment: Please don't capitalise random words. Doing that makes questions hard to read.

Comment: Your code will set the value to 2218 if there is no number already saved. If there is a number already saved, it will increment that. What you want it to do is to just use the saved number without modifying it, and only increment it (and re-store it in localStorage) in the code that runs when the form is submitted.

Comment: can you please help me how can i do that